# regex find match within the first n items

Tags: regex

I have a string of *8 separated hexadecimal numbers*, such as:

```
3E%12%3%1F%3E%6%1%19
```

And I need to check if the number `12` is located within the *first 4 set of numbers*.

I'm guessing this shouldn't be all that complex, but my searches turned up empty. Regular expressions are always a trouble for me, but I don't have access to anything else in this scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any particular language other than regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([^%]+%){0,3}12%
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/eK9oG9/3)

---

The idea is:

- `^` - from the start
- `[^%]+%` - match multiple non **%** characters, followed by a **%** character
- `{0,3}` - between *0* and *3* of those
- `12%` - `12%` after that

Comment: Thanks! Works great.

Comment: %123% is also match and a false positive I think

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
^([^%]*%){4}(?<=.*12.*)
```

This will match both the following if that is what is intended

```
1%312%..
1%123%..
```

Check the solution if %123% is matched or not

If the number 12 should stand on its own then use

```
^([^%]*%){4}(?<=.*\b12\b.*)
```